# no such item with ID xxxx open blocks xp drain

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods, minecraft-java-edition-server

I have a private forge modded server that I use to take some of the load off of my main computer. I was playing along and attempted to craft a open blocks xp drain and even though I could see it in the crafting bench, when i attempted to take the item out, it just vanished. I have already fixed all the item and block id conflicts that I can and have been playing on the server for a while.

I also attempted to give myself the item via both the server console and client side /give and I got the error message in the title. The client and server are using identical config files, and I double checked that the ID was not doubled up via grep.

thanks for any help anyone can give.

Answer (score 1):

The only reason i can see here is that the server and client have mismatched ids. The client thinks that the item exist at this ID but the server doesn't recognise it. I would like for you to double check again. If it doesn't work, copy the config file and replace the client one with the server one. This ensures consistency as they are now confirmed to use the same file.

Comment: I did this when I set up the server, and i have not chagned anything since. I also checked the open blocks config files and made sure that the id for that item was identical

Comment: try copying and pasting replacing one config file with another. If it still doesnt work, make sure that the mod is installed on the server.